# How to update data type of a field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, type-conversion, kibana

I am publishing a data to elasticsearch using fluentd. It has a field `Data.CPU` which is currently set to `string`. Index name is `health_gateway`

[image]

I have made some changes in python code which is generating the data so now this field `Data.CPU` has now become `integer`. But still elasticsearch is showing it as string. How can I update it data type.

I tried running below commands in kibana dev tools:

```
PUT health_gateway/doc/_mapping
{
    "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
            "Data.CPU" : {"type" : "integer"}
        }
    }
}
```

But it gave me below error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

There is also this [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) which says using `mutate` we can convert the data type but I am not able to understand it properly.

I do not want to delete the index and recreate as I have created a visualization based on this index and after deleting it will also be deleted. Can anyone please help in this.

Comment: The document you linked to is about Logstash - can you confirm whether you're using Logstash of Fluentd?

Comment: No I am using fluentd. Fluentd is uploading all my logs from  ubuntu machine to elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can update the mapping, by [indexing the same field in multiple ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex) i.e by using multi fields**.

Using the below mapping, `Data.CPU.raw` will be of `integer` type

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Data": {
        "properties": {
          "CPU": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**OR you can create a new index with correct index mapping, and reindex the data in  it using the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex)**

Comment: In your mapping, where are you defining index pattern. I have mulitple index created so I think we have to also mention the index that Data.CPU belongs to.?

Comment: @SAndrew are you using an index template to create the index, and in that you have defined `index_pattern`

Comment: @SAndrew did you try by using `multi fields` as shown in my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't change the mapping of a field that already exists in a given index, as explained in the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings).

The specific error you got is because you included `/doc/` in your request path (you probably wanted `/<index>/_mapping`), but fixing this alone won't be sufficient.

Finally, I'm not sure you really have a dot in the field name there. Last I heard it wasn't possible to use dots in field names.

Nevertheless, there are several ways forward in your situation... here are a couple of them:

### Use a scripted field

You can add a scripted field to the Kibana index-pattern. It's quick to implement, but has major performance implications. You can read more about them on the Elastic blog [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields) (especially under the heading "**Match a number and return that match**").

### Add a new multi-field

You could add a [new multifield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex). The example below assumes that `CPU` is a nested field under `Data`, rather than *really* being called `Data.CPU` with a literal `.`:

```
PUT health_gateway/_mapping
{
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
      "Data": {
        "properties": {
          "CPU": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "int": {
                "type": "short"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Reindex your data within ES

Use the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html). Be sure to set the correct mapping on the target index.

### Delete and reindex everything from source

If you are able to regenerate the data from source in a timely manner, without disrupting users, you can simply delete the index and reingest all your data with an updated mapping.